# Relationship between a,b and c that make the equation system have infinite solutions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations, numerical-linear-algebra, python

i have this matrix

\begin{cases}
\phantom{2}x_1+2x_2-3x_3=a\\
2x_1+3x_2+3x_3=b\\
5x_1+9x_2-6x_3=c\\
\end{cases}

And the excercise says that i have to find the relationship between a, b, c that makes that the set of equations to have infinite solutions. I have to use python for this but i dont know for where to start. The excercise says at the end *"Declare a,b,c as symbolic variables"*

Comment: Welcome to MSE. If your question is about programming syntax then here is not the right place to ask it. You might want to check stackoverflow instead. On the other hand, if your question is about the mathematics behind systems of linear equations, I suggest remove the code.

Comment: @Saeed Thanks. I removed the code.

Comment: @OmarCastañeda This is clearly an exercise so please share your thoughts first.

Comment: @KBS I tried first using the library sympy in python to try a resolve the excercise declaring a, b, c as symbolic variables. But python just return  the same initial equations.

Comment: I would suggest you to look at the mathematical problem first and understand under what condition you have an infinite number of solution. The implementation should come after.

Comment: @KBS Thanks right. I'm new in linear algebra and i saw this excercise but i don't quite understand yet what is the meaning of infinite solutions in this case.

Comment: In this case, check that: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations

Comment: @KBS Hey, thanks for your suggestion. I made some digging in the topic and i made a gauss elimination as my answer to this post show. But i wanted to be sure that the result indeed means an infinite number of solutions. And i want to know if some of you knows how to show this same in python. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As @KBS suggested, after learning a little bit more i made a Gaussian elimination process on the matrix and this is the result:

\begin{cases}
\phantom{2}x_1+2x_2-3x_3=a\\
0x_1-1x_2+9x_3=b-2a\\
0x_1+0x_2-0x_3=3a-c+b\\
\end{cases}

This mean that the system has infinite solutions, right?. And how can i make this same process in python and show this result?.

Comment: This is the right way. Now, look at the third equation; you can rewrite it as $0=3a-c+b$. When does this equation have infinitely many solutions? When does it have no solution?

Comment: @Taladris, Mmm i would say that the system have infinite solutions because either a, b or c can be expresed in terms of the other two. So any values are possible?.

Comment: Not quite. If $3a-c+b\neq 0$, then the last equation, hence the system, has no solution. If $3a-c+b=0$, then you can express $x_1$ and $x_2$ as linear functions of $x_3$, so there are infinitely many solutions.

Comment: @Taladris Oh!. I test that in Sympy and yeah, if i give a,b,c any values != 0 the result is empty meaning that there are no solutions. But if a,b,c = 0 then i get this. x: -15*z  y: 9*z . So any values of X and Y depends on Z, meaning that there are infinite solutions.

Comment: Now i understand. Thanks!